# Is something wrong with my FQL?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I keep getting unexpected variable error. All i'm trying to do is fetch list of friends       who are also app users

```
   $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        $fql =  'SELECT uid, name, is_app_user, pic_square
                FROM user WHERE uid
                IN
               (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
                AND is_app_user = 1'
        $param =    array(
                          'method' => 'fql.query',
                          'query' => $fql,
                             );
         $fqlresult = $facebook->api($param);

         $fqlresult   =   $this->facebook->api($param);
         foreach($fqlresult as $result)
        {
         print_r($result);
         print($result['name']);
         }
```

Answer (score 2):

> I keep getting unexpected variable error.

You mean a **PHP error message** – and you get a file name and line number with it.

And of course you are getting it – because you are missing a semicolon …

```
$fql =  'SELECT uid, name, is_app_user, pic_square
            FROM user WHERE uid
            IN
           (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
            AND is_app_user = 1'
$param =    array(
```

… after the declaration of `$fql`’s value, so that `$param` on the next line comes unexpected to the parser.

**Dude, please get some *basic PHP knowledge*, before continuing to play around with complex APIs.**

Answer (score 0):

Your fql is correct, you can test it here [FQL Query](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20uid%2C%20name,%20is_app_user,%20pic_square%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me%28%29%29%20AND%20is_app_user%20=%201), I suggest you to check the php function calls as I see you have both

```
     $fqlresult = $facebook->api($param);

     $fqlresult   =   $this->facebook->api($param);
```

and I'm not sure what you want to achieve with the double call.

You can find more details on how to use FQL and the Facebook PHP SDK here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/